# Does the spouse of a British citizen with an EEA residence permit need a visa to travel to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, spouses

Does the spouse of British citizen with EEA permanent residence need a visa to travel to the UK?

Comment: What nationality is the spouse?

Comment: @GayotFow care to add a relevant quote? I can only find the manual in a FOI request from 2011, so it might be severely outdated

Comment: @GayotFow that chart doesn't show any exceptions for Ireland residents, spouse or not. Am I correct in my reading of it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Consider someone with a residence permit for France and they want to visit the UK and what we would tell them. Visa nationals require an entry clearance.

Comment: @JonathanReez I can upload a fresh copy of that page into a new answer because 'pnuts' has (curiously) made his a wiki. If so you can ping me

Comment: @GayotFow yes, please upload it, along with a link to the source

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=gb&SUBSECTION=VS&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a "Family Member" Residence Card marked
>     "Permanent Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union
>     Citizen  or  Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union
>     Citizen  issued by another EEA Member State (but **not** Switzerland) to family
>     members of an EEA national or national of
>     Switzerland if traveling with or traveling to join the EEA
>     national or national of Switzerland.

and

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a "Family Member" Residence Card  marked
>     "4EUFAM" issued by Ireland (Rep.) to family members of an
>     EEA national or national of Switzerland if
>     traveling with or traveling to join the EEA national or
>     national of Switzerland.

So, if you hold one of those documents **and** are travelling with **or** to join your spouse, you do **not** need a visa. Otherwise, you **do** need a visa if you're a visa national

Comment: ... never mind that an EEA Family Permit is effectively a visa.  Image search reveals that some of them even explicitly identify themselves as "VISA EEA FP."

Comment: "As a general rule, family members of British citizens do not qualify for an EEA family permit. Article 3 of the Directive essentially says that an EEA national cannot be considered as exercising freedom of movement in their own State -"  From https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eea-family-permits-eun02/eea-family-permit-eun02#eun29-how-do-i-establish-dependency-under-the-eea-regulations

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks, had forgotten about that. Changed my answer

Comment: @GayotFow but the family member of a British citizen *who is resident in another EU country **does*** qualify for an EEA family permit, under the Surinder Singh ruling, and can use it for visa-free travel to the UK under the McCarthy ruling.

Comment: "it" in my previous comment should read "her article 10 residence card"; if she has one, an EEA Family Permit should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I am a British citizen living in France with my Russian wife who has a Carte de Séjour. We intend to visit the UK (together) soon.
Have a look at the following link.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

I would recommend writing to or calling UK Visas and Immigration to be sure.